# Google Optimize Experiment targeting wrong URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, targeting, google-optimize, google-experiments

I've setup an experiment on a specific URL in which I send no traffic 
(same domain name that I use for other landing pages but with different parameter in the URL)

I've started the experiment few days ago without sending any traffic
And now I see that the experiment got triggered around 5000 times.
I double checked on my analytics reports and I see no access to the main page that is supposed to trigger the test. To explain with example:

This is what I have running:

> http://domain1/landingpages?id=1
>
> http://domain1/landingpages?id=2

this is the test that I created:

> http://domain1/landingpages?id=3

with a 50% redirect on:

> http://domain1/landingpages?id=4

The Experiment should only be triggered on id=3 page, but it did got triggered with id=1 and id=2 pages. Any idea how I can make the trigger only happen when "id=3" is in the url ?
Currently my configuration is as follow:

> "WHEN Url Matches "http://domain1/landingpages?id=3"  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URL targeting documentation](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6283424?hl=en#match-types) explains your situation. (Emphasize by me.)

> Use matches when there are query string parameters in URLs that you
>   don’t want to include in the matching. Matches can be more flexible
>   than equals because it adheres to the following rules:
>
> - **Ignores query string parameters** and fragments.
> - Case insensitive.
> - Normalized to remove a www. prefix.
> - Normalized to a remove a trailing slash.
> - HTTP and HTTPS are optional (HTTP will match HTTPS).

Verifying this in Optimize:
[image]

So you should either simply select `Equals` operator and use `http://domain1/landingpages?id=3` as a value.

If other parameters might occur, then you could build a `regex` for this, to containt id=3 among various parameters. E.g.:

```
http:\/\/domain1\/landingpages\?(.*&)?id=3(&|$)
```

Optionally, you can use [Query parameter targating](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6301786?hl=en&ref_topic=6283433), and build a rule for the base URL, and for the id parameter separately.

Comment: thanks for clear answer and sorry not seeing it in documentation before